# Why can I not install a package from a repo I just added using Chef?

Tags: chef-infra

I have the following in a Chef recipe:

```
cookbook_file '/etc/yum.repos.d/wandisco-svn.repo' do
  source 'wandisco-svn.repo'
end

execute 'yum clean all'

package 'subversion' do
  action :install
end
```

After provisioning the server with Chef, the wrong version of Subversion is installed (an old version from the other yum repos). I can immediately run `yum list subversion` and see the correct version is available.

If I do the above manually (create the file, run a `yum clean all`, and run `yum install subversion`), the correct version is installed.

Why doesn't the above code work correctly?

Comment: I've started a meta conversation about this question: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/283778/1454117

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Chef caches the yum package database in memory in order to speed up recipe execution. You can flush it by using:

```
yum_package 'subversion' do
  flush_cache before: true
end
```

instead of your existing package resource.

Comment: I appreciate the answer, and I think you are right. Sadly, in my real world case I'll have to fork the cookbook that includes the `package` call to use `yum_package` instead. I'll be researching if there are other ways to clear Chef's yum cache inline, which would work better in my case. Accepted goes to you for correctly identifying the problem in my simplified example though, so thank you.

Answer (score 1):

[The answer provided by coderanger](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27974885/1454117) points out the problem with the code. You can also solve the problem by using `yum_repository` to make Chef aware you are adding a repository (as opposed to adding an arbitrary file to the filesystem and executing an arbitrary command):

```
yum_repository 'wandisco-svn' do
  description 'Wandisco SVN Repo'
  baseurl 'http://opensource.wandisco.com/centos/6/svn-1.8/RPMS/$basearch/'
  gpgcheck false
  enabled true
end

package 'subversion' do
  action :install
end
```

By default, `yum_repository` handles refreshing both the Chef cache and the Yum cache. There are a lot of different options to setup the repository the way you need. Documentation can be found on the [chef-cookbooks/yum GitHub repository](https://github.com/chef-cookbooks/yum).